# Reading Content Security Policy header with Manifest 3 - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We are working on an Open Source Chrome extension: [Digital Assistant Client](https://github.com/Digital-Assistant/Digital_Assistant_Client)

We are trying to read and modify the "content security policy" header with chrome extension in manifest 3. We are using the declarativeNetRequest api for modification with append operation to allow our domains for fetching and posting data. In manifest v2 it is easy to read the header values by using

`chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener( onHeadersReceived, onHeaderFilter, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders'] );`

How can we acheive this in manifest 3 for reading the headers?

I have tried by defining the rules.json as given below

`[ { "id": 1, "action": { "type": "modifyHeaders", "responseHeaders": [ { "header": "content-security-policy", "operation": "append", "value": "connect-src udan.nistapp.ai udantest.nistapp.ai" } ] }, "condition": { "resourceTypes": [ "csp_report", "font", "image", "main_frame", "media", "object", "other", "ping", "script", "stylesheet", "sub_frame", "webbundle", "websocket", "webtransport", "xmlhttprequest" ] } } ]`

and in manifest as given below

`.... permissions": [ .... "declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess", "declarativeNetRequestFeedback", ], "declarative_net_request": { "rule_resources": [{ "id": "csp_rules", "enabled": true, "path": "rules.json" }] }, ....`

**Problem:**

When i try to append the value to the original, connect-src is getting overridden. So i want to read the header values such that i can modify the existing values. Is there a way for acheiving this?

Comment: No, ManifestV3 can't modify/append CSP header because per the specification an addendum can only further restrict the header, not alter it. You'll have to use a force-instaled extension to keep using webRequestBlocking API.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have looks good for modifying the CSP header. With that in mind, there are two common gotchas which you might be running in to:

- Certain DNR rules that access or modify request/response data require host permissions. Make sure you have the `host_permissions` key set in the manifest with the hosts you wish to act on.
- Modifications to headers made with DNR are not shown in Dev Tools (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1247400). Doing a fetch request from the console and logging headers can help, or using the (development only) [onRuleMatchedDebug](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#event-onRuleMatchedDebug) API to see if your rule has been run.

Comment: When i try to append the value to the original, connect-src is getting overridden. So i want to read the header values such that i can modify the existing values. Is there a way for acheiving this?